# How to access request in stream interceptor?

Tags: go, grpc

I have a unary interceptor that contains the following code:

```golang
func (m Middlewares) LocationInterceptor(c context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (interface{}, error) {
    ctx := c.(HarmonyContext)
    location, ok := req.(interface{ GetLocation() *corev1.Location })
    if !ok {
        panic("location middleware used on message without a location")
    }
    
    ctx.Location := location.GetLocation()

    return handler(c, req)
}
```

How would I be able to convert this to a stream interceptor, if I know that the stream will definitely only stream from server to client? In addition, is there any way to make it only intercept when the moment the stream begins?

```golang
func (m Middlewares) LocationInterceptorStream(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
    wrappedStream := ss.(HarmonyWrappedServerStream)

    return handler(srv, wrappedStream)
}
```

Comment: Is your RPC a unary one or a streaming one? Only unary interceptors would be invoked for unary RPCs and only streaming interceptors would be invoked for streaming RPCs.

And in the case of streaming RPCs, your interceptor would only be invoked when the stream begins, not for every new message on the stream. You could implement a custom stream if you want the latter behavior though.

Comment: I am trying to convert a unary interceptor to a streaming interceptor. The unary interceptor asserts the request to an interface that lets me access the `Location` field of the payload, but I can't find a similar feature in streaming interceptors.

Comment: I'm with the same issue. There was no update in this topic in a while. Did you get the answer @Bluskript ?

Answer (score 0):

For a "server streaming RPC", the client sends one message (the request), and the server responds with multiple messages. In the stream interceptor, you need to call `ServerStream.RecvMsg(...)` once to get the request from the client. You will then need to pass a "wrapped stream" into `handler` which will later return this message on the first call to `RecvMsg`. For gRPC using protobuf messages, you can do something like the following. This `serverStreamWrapper` will allow you to call `peekRequest(...)` in the interceptor to get the request, then pass the stream on to the handler.

For this specific example, you may also be able to implement the logic in the wrapped `RecvMsg(...)` function itself. This function gets called by gRPC to read the request from the client to the server. This may be simpler than trying to store the request.

```golang
type serverStreamWrapper struct {
    peekedRequest proto.Message
    wrappedStream grpc.ServerStream
}

func newServerStreamWrapper(stream grpc.ServerStream) *serverStreamWrapper {
    return &serverStreamWrapper{nil, stream}
}

func (s *serverStreamWrapper) peekRequest(msg interface{}) error {
    protoMsg := msg.(proto.Message)
    if protoMsg == nil {
        panic("BUG: msg must not be nil")
    }
    if s.peekedRequest != nil {
        panic("BUG: Must only called peekRequest once")
    }

    err := s.wrappedStream.RecvMsg(protoMsg)
    if err == nil {
        s.peekedRequest = protoMsg
    }
    return err
}

func (s *serverStreamWrapper) RecvMsg(msg interface{}) error {
    if s.peekedRequest != nil {
        protoMsg := msg.(proto.Message)
        proto.Reset(protoMsg)
        proto.Merge(protoMsg, s.peekedRequest)
        s.peekedRequest = nil
        return nil
    }
    return s.wrappedStream.RecvMsg(msg)
}
```